# How to find the vnet/subnet associated with an Azure Virtual Machine using java sdk?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, vnet

I am using Java SDK to collect the Azure Virutal Machines. However I am not able to figure out the vnet/subnet associated with the VM. The SDK doesn't provide this info directly and the REST API as well.

Comment: The SDK will not show the vnet/subnet information if you just get the VM through the SDK.

Comment: Thats exactly my problem.. How could we get that info? I am trying to get the vnet/subnet info through network interface but its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out and posting the answer . We need to get it from the Primary IP Configuration associated with the primary network interface. Please let me know if anyone has a better solution.

```
NicIPConfiguration ipConfiguration = virtualMachine.getPrimaryNetworkInterface().primaryIPConfiguration();

String vnet = ipConfiguration.networkId();
String subnet = ipConfiguration.subnetName();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the VNet and Subnet name associated with the VM

```
String vNet = virtualmachine.getPrimaryNetworkInterface().primaryIPConfiguration().getNetwork().name();
String subnet = virtualmachine.getPrimaryNetworkInterface().primaryIPConfiguration().subnetName();
```